# Approaches to Serializing an Object Graph with Circular References

Tags: c#, serialization, circular-reference

Let's suppose that I want to implement a serializer (C#) for the sake of practice, and I would want the said serializer to not fail on circular references.

The apparent solution would be to only serialize objects which were not yet encountered and skipping objects which were. This is easily accomplished by hashing the instances (in one way or another).

The proposed solution bids the question: "What defines an object's identity?"
One would say - leave it up to the GetHashCode and Equals methods.
This is an acceptable solution- which conserves time on serialization and conserves memory on de-serialization.

However, this is not always a desirable outcome, since many instances may have the same identity yet used for completely different things in the serialized domain, so that de-serializing them later on as the same instance would violate the domain logic.

So, as an author of such a serializer, I must leave it up to the caller to make such decisions.

One approach to solve this would be to Hash a collection per the said type, and distinguishing between serialized and non serialized instances by iterating the collection and invoking ReferenceEquals on each contained element.
This works, but is sub-optimal - performance wise.

Another approach is to Pin objects in the unmanaged heap, and use the pinned object address as an identity, which seems kind of an overkill and has a lot of overhead as well.

Another approach is to use reflection to invoke the Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode default implementations of every instance- which seems to solve the problem, but has its own little overhead.

My questions are:

1)Are there any caveats which I have missed to the approaches I've suggested?
2)Are there any more additional approaches which I might have not thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/objectidgenerator.cs,b9dd7357a53b8a9c). It does exactly that.

According to the MSDN page:

> Using a hash table, the ObjectIDGenerator retains which ID is assigned to which object. The object references, which uniquely identify each object, are addresses in the runtime garbage-collected heap. Object reference values can change during serialization, but the table is updated automatically so the information is correct.

The source code is also available [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/objectidgenerator.cs,b9dd7357a53b8a9c).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that would actually cause circular references (i.e. a neverending loop in your app) is actual object references. So don't keep a list of hashes, keep a list of the previously encountered objects themselves.

If you want to keep the serialised data as small as possible, you could implement it similar to how nuget organises the packages folder - write each object out once, but where one object references another, write a reference key of some sort.

```
[
    {
        serialisationKey: "GUID1",
        name: "Neil",
        friends: [
            { obj: "GUID2" },
            { obj: "GUID3" }
        ]
    },
    {
        serialisationKey: "GUID2",
        name: "Bob",
        friends: [
            { obj: "GUID1" }
        ]
    },
    {
        serialisationKey: "GUID3",
        name: "Alf",
        friends: [
            { obj: "GUID1" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You suggest that I use the first proposed approach. I value your input but it does not answer any of my two questions. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pin to memory! You can use [`object.ReferenceEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your serializer shouldn't be smart and try to figure out if the same object needs to be serialized as one object or as two. Serialize each object once - if the object is referenced twice, reference it twice in the serialized data.

Comment: You suggest that I use the first proposed approach. I value your input but it does not answer any of my two questions. Or am I missing something?